# html webpage with mouseovers convert data to json

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the data on the mouseovers on the map at the bottom of this webpage with what planes are in the air atm fighting bush fires, link o web page http://dsewebapps.dse.vic.gov.au/fires/updates/report/aircraft/aircraftlist.htm

[image: screengrab of data i want]

Now I can extract the beginning and end of the map and also I can exract the area's, for example this is the code I have tired and the results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
url = "http://dsewebapps.dse.vic.gov.au/fires/updates/report/aircraft/aircraftlist.htm"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

#find the map at the bottom of the page with all the codinates in it
findmap = soup.find_all("area")
print(findmap[1]).prettitfy
```

this code results in printing out just one of the planes, which is fine here.

```
<bound method Tag.prettify of <area coords="87,369,6" href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseout=" return nd()" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;p class=PopupText&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;BOMBER 352&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Last Observation: &lt;/STRONG&gt;Feb 10 2014 10:26AM&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Speed: &lt;/STRONG&gt;0 Knots&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Course: &lt;/STRONG&gt;0 Deg True&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Latitude: &lt;/STRONG&gt;-37.6074 &lt;STRONG&gt;Longitude: &lt;/STRONG&gt;141.362 &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Bomber 362&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Last Observation: &lt;/STRONG&gt;Feb 10 2014 10:29AM&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Speed: &lt;/STRONG&gt;0 Knots&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Course: &lt;/STRONG&gt;0 Deg True&lt;br&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Latitude: &lt;/STRONG&gt;-37.6072 &lt;STRONG&gt;Longitude: &lt;/STRONG&gt;141.362 &lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;',ABOVE)" shape="circle"></area>>
```

I would idealy like to convert these paragraphs into json, so i can feed it into something else, so am i better off doing a lot of regex's? or can BeautifulSoup work with this data and parse it into JSON, as from what i have read it can't because of the javascript. Or is there another option?

Thx.

Comment: Which data do you need to put in Json? `coords` or things like `LastObservation = 'Feb 10 2014 10:26AM'`, `Speed = '0 knots'` etc.?

Comment: would like all of it, but if i had to pick it would be... name of plane, last ob, lat / long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using BeautifulSoup.

The example here after follows the following algorithm:

1. Iterate over all `<area>` elements
2. Use the `coords` attribute as index to store the area's data in the result dicitonary
3. Parse the `onmouseover` attribute of the `<area>` elements using the following rules:

   - The html to parse starts after the `return overlib('` string and ends before the `',ABOVE` string
   - Every plane record starts with the plane's name enclosed in `<strong>` html element, followed by non-text element (`<p/>` in this case but I test it as `element.name != None`), followed by another `<strong element>`

Bellow is my sample code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

url = "http://dsewebapps.dse.vic.gov.au/fires/updates/report/aircraft/aircraftlist.htm"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

fields = ['Last Observation', 'Speed', 'Course', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']

areas = dict()
for area in soup.find_all("area"):
    area_coords = area.get('coords')
    print area_coords
    data_soup = BeautifulSoup(area.get('onmouseover')[len("return overlib('"):
                                                      -len("',ABOVE")])
    planes = list()
    elements = data_soup.find_all('p')[0].contents
    for i in range(len(elements) - 2):
    if elements[i].name == 'strong' and \
        elements[i+1].name and \
        elements[i+2].name == 'strong':
        plane = dict()
        plane[u'Name'] = elements[i].contents[0]
        planes.append(plane)
    if hasattr(elements[i], 'contents') and len(elements[i].contents) > 0:
        field_name = elements[i].contents[0].strip(' :')
        if field_name in fields:
            plane[field_name] = elements[i+1]
    areas[area_coords] = planes
pp.pprint(areas)
```

Comment: adding `for z in range(0, len(findmap) - 1):` under the `findmap=soup...` section will print all the items. However i get the problem, that some of the _onmouseover_ items contain multiple aircraft and it misses them. (see the picture in the initial question for example of the onmouseover event showing multiple items.)

Comment: See my updated answer. Now the code parses all areas and all plane records in every area. Hope this helps more. :)

Comment: Awesome, thx, pretty comprehensive. Will have a better play at work on Monday ;)

Answer (score 0):

using lxml, might be a little better than regex...

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> t1 = etree.parse(url, parser)
# use xpath to extract onmouseover
>>> o = t1.xpath('//area[2]/@onmouseover')[0]
# delete javascript function call from both sides, yep, that's the ugly part...
>>> h = o[len("return overlib('"):-len("',ABOVE)")]
>>> t2 = etree.fromstring(h, parser)
# note the [1:] to remove first unwanted strong tag
# also note the use of zip here
>>> {k:v for k,v in zip(t2.xpath('//strong/text()')[1:], t2.xpath('//p/text()'))}
{'Latitude: ': '-34.232 ', 'Last Observation: ': 'Feb  9 2014  6:36PM', 
 'Speed: ': '3 Knots', 'Course: ': '337 Deg True', 'Longitude: ': '142.086 '}
```